# Swift after json parsing variables are assigned to their initial values

Tags: swift, cocoa

I'm new to swift i am sorry if this is a stupid question
I am trying to expand my knowledge in macOS development and i am trying out new things
i am parsing a json file from an url
it works fine in the do{}catch{} brackets however, i want to use what i get from the json data in other parts of the program.

i created some variables to store the values.

However, they go back to their initial value once the do{}catch{} execution is done
how can i store the values I got

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        var summonerNameGlobal: String = ""
        var summonerIdGlobal: String = ""
        var summonerPuuidGlobal: String = ""
        var summonerAccountIdGlobal: String = ""
        let jsonString = "https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/john?api_key=\(apiKey)"
        guard let url = URL(string: jsonString) else {return}
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
            guard let data = data else {return}
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                do {
                    let summoner = try JSONDecoder().decode(SummonerInfo.self, from: data)
                    self.summonerIdLabel.stringValue = summoner.id
                    summonerNameGlobal = summoner.name
                    summonerIdGlobal = summoner.id
                    summonerAccountIdGlobal = summoner.accountId
                    summonerPuuidGlobal = summoner.puuid
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }.resume()
        print(summonerNameGlobal)
        print(summonerPuuidGlobal)
        print(summonerIdGlobal)
        print(summonerAccountIdGlobal)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not going to default again but you are checking them before they are being set ... because `async function` take some time to get response from server but your `print` statements run `immediately`
What you can do is to check values once they are set

```
func callApi(completion: @escaping (SummonerInfo?)->Void){
       
        let jsonString = "https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/john?api_key=\(apiKey)"
        guard let url = URL(string: jsonString) else {return}
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
            guard let data = data else {return}
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                do {
                    let summoner = try JSONDecoder().decode(SummonerInfo.self, from: data)
                   completion(summoner)
                } catch {
                    completion(nil)
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
       
        callApi { [weak self] info  in
            
            if let getInfo = info {
            print(getInfo.name)
            print(getInfo.id)
            print(getInfo.accountId)
            print(getInfo.puuid)
            } else  {
                print("data is nil")
            }
            
        }
        
      
    }
```

Comment: really appreciate the help